# Does Angular run change detection only for components that are active by either primary or auxiliary routing?

Tags: angular

Does Angular run change detection only for components that are  active by either primary or auxiliary routing?

Comment: Angular runs change detection for components that are instantiated.

Comment: Can I put it like this. Change detection will run only for components that are instantiated and not yet destroyed. Destruction of component can happen during routing, isn't it?

Comment: Since you change routes, yes, your previous component is destroyed.

Comment: @TibinThomas did your doubt got resolved? If yes, then please update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once any component like textbox are setup, angular bings CD observer on that and it continues till the parent component is alive.
For example--
Lets say you have setup a filter on a textbox based on which you filter a list... If you type something and then navigate away from the page, the filter event will be called before the page gets unloaded.. You can check via placing logging event in the filter handler.